# Why am i getting this 'error': Could not open a connection to your authentication agent after using ssh-add on cmder on windows

Tags: ssh

I'm following the tutsplus course and on the 4th section, 2nd lesson, in order to get a SSH key, you have to type in `ssh-agent -s`. That parts fine as I get this feedback: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-invtd8nFEaXG/agent.10788; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=5264; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 5264;` However, when I try to do the `ssh-add c:/Users/ArqamWD/.ssh/id_rsa`, this error appears, `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` Im on CMDER on windows 10 and i've tried so many answers on this site and others but none seem to work, please help, thank you.

Comment: Try `eval $(ssh-agent)`.

Comment: @phd I tried, that doesn't work on my CMDER I then changed to bash and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. I just ran across this problem and resolved it by setting my permissions on the private key file with chmod to 0400 or 0600.